# Вопрос по вёрстке под мобильные устройства

Tags: html, css

Допустим, есть блок DIV 100*100px.
В браузере на компе блок отображается нормально, в масштабе 100%.
В браузере на мобильном устройстве DIV выглядит уменьшенным, так как количество пикселей на дюйм выше.

Как решить проблему отображения блоков в разных размерах с визуальной точки зрения, чтобы и на компе, и на смартфоне они были одинаковы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В head напишите следующее:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

А пиксели на дюйм не причем. Если вы с помощью JS проверите размер вьюпорта, то он будет меньше, чем реальное количество пикселей в вашем устройстве

Comment: Этот метатэг прописан. Он позволяет дизайну адаптироваться. Но от вышеописанной проблемы он не избавляет.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов странные заморочки. Ну меньше он чутка и что? Элементы относительно друг друга будут абсолютно такими же как и на компьютере.

Comment: Возможно, вы правы, а мне перфекционизм покоя не даёт.

Comment: Хотя нет, нашёл решение. Через медиазапросы.

Answer (score 0):

[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) в помощь

Comment: весёлая ссылка получилась :)